What does the "timeline score" of a question mean?
If you go to some questions and open history, you might see "timeline score: _". What does that mean? Does it mean the number of upvotes - downvotes? Or is it just saying who upvoted/downvoted a post?

Let remind ourselves that votes are private and there is no UI that reveals who voted on a post. That would be a serious bug.

When you see an entry in a timeline with a 'timeline score: ,' that corresponds to an answer added. The timeline is a link to the timeline of the answer, and the score is the score of the answer.
Example:


I think this would be clearer if those two elements were the other way around.

Why would that be there? We can see the score already

@AndyK To quickly see the score of all the answers without having to go back and scroll down I guess.
